# How to write the given loop efficiently?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

Any efficient way to write the following loop? dataPLprocessed is a time-series data and I want to calculate the score based on rolling 7 days percentile value (see the loop below for more explanation).

```
for i in len(dataPLprocessed):
    if (dataPLprocessed.rolling(‘7D’)['lineardifference'].rank(pct=True)[i]<.05) or (
            dataPLprocessed.rolling(‘7D’)['lineardifference'].rank(pct=True)[i]>.95) :
        dataPLprocessed['score'] =10
    elif (dataPLprocessed.rolling(‘7D’)['lineardifference'].rank(pct=True)[i] < .1)or (
            dataPLprocessed.rolling(‘7D’)['lineardifference'].rank(pct=True)[i] > .9):
        dataPLprocessed['score'] = 9
    elif (dataPLprocessed.rolling(‘7D’)['lineardifference'].rank(pct=True)[i] < .15) or (
            dataPLprocessed.rolling(‘7D’)['lineardifference'].rank(pct=True)[i] > .85):
        dataPLprocessed['score'] = 8
    elif (dataPLprocessed.rolling(‘7D’)['lineardifference'].rank(pct=True)[i] < .2) or (
            dataPLprocessed.rolling(‘7D’)['lineardifference'].rank(pct=True)[i] > .8):
        dataPLprocessed['score'] = 7
    elif (dataPLprocessed.rolling(‘7D’)['lineardifference'].rank(pct=True)[i] < .25)or (
            dataPLprocessed.rolling(‘7D’)['lineardifference'].rank(pct=True)[i] > .75):
        dataPLprocessed['score'] = 6
    elif (dataPLprocessed.rolling(‘7D’)['lineardifference'].rank(pct=True)[i] < .3)or (
            dataPLprocessed.rolling(‘7D’)['lineardifference'].rank(pct=True)[i] > .7):
        dataPLprocessed['score'] = 5
    elif (dataPLprocessed.rolling(‘7D’)['lineardifference'].rank(pct=True)[i] < .35) or (
            dataPLprocessed.rolling(‘7D’)['lineardifference'].rank(pct=True)[i] > .65):
        dataPLprocessed['score'] = 4
    elif (dataPLprocessed.rolling(‘7D’)['lineardifference'].rank(pct=True)[i] < .4) or (
            dataPLprocessed.rolling(‘7D’)['lineardifference'].rank(pct=True)[i] > .6):
        dataPLprocessed['score'] = 3
    elif (dataPLprocessed.rolling(‘7D’)['lineardifference'].rank(pct=True)[i] < .45) or (
            dataPLprocessed.rolling(‘7D’)['lineardifference'].rank(pct=True)[i] > .55):
        dataPLprocessed['score'] = 2
    else:
        dataPLprocessed['score'] = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

It would probably help to avoid the repetitive data access code to get the to the rank value:

```
for i in len(dataPLprocessed):
    rank = dataPLprocessed.rolling('7D')['lineardifference'].rank(pct=True)[i]
    if   rank < 0.05 or rank > 0.95: score = 10
    elif rank < 0.1  or rank > 0.9:  score = 9
    elif rank < 0.15 or rank > 0.85: score = 8
    elif rank < 0.2  or rank > 0.8:  score = 7
    elif rank < 0.25 or rank > 0.75: score = 6
    elif rank < 0.3  or rank > 0.7:  score = 5
    elif rank < 0.35 or rank > 0.65: score = 4
    elif rank < 0.4  or rank > 0.6:  score = 3
    elif rank < 0.45 or rank > 0.55: score = 2
    else:                            score = 1
    dataPLprocessed['score'] = score
```

If that is still not improvement enough, you could probably shave off a few additional milliseconds by using binary searches to compute the scores:

```
from bisect import bisect_left, bisect_right
loRanks  = [0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.25, 0.3, 0.35, 0.4, 0.45]
hiRanks  = [0.55, 0.6, 0.65, 0.7, 0.75, 0.8, 0.85, 0.9, 0.95]
def getScore(rank):
    if rank<0.45: return 10-bisect_right(loRanks,rank)
    else:         return 1+bisect_left(hiRanks,rank)


for i in len(dataPLprocessed):
    rank = dataPLprocessed.rolling('7D')['lineardifference'].rank(pct=True)[i]
    dataPLprocessed['score'] =  getScore(rank)
```

Comment: Couldn't you also just write a while loop and have .05 added/subtracted from the previous value and subtracting 1 from score after each iteration until reaching the given threshhold?

Comment: You could but that would be less efficient than a binary search.  Most of the performance boost will come from getting `rank` at the start instead of on every comparison.  The while-loop vs if/elif/else makes an insignificant difference in comparison.